How to replace a broken grounding screw in the weatherproof receptacle box?
Homeowner here, first time working on an outdoor receptacle. When I was trying to replace the old GFCI receptacle and put a new cover on the box to weatherproof, I broke the grounding screw as it was rusted (left upper corner in the first photo). Replacing the box is not an easy option for me as it’s screwed to metal light pole and screws are rusted and not accessible by the tools I have. So, I am looking a way of grounding the receptacle. Can I use ground clamp (where does it go so that it does not interfere with the cover I will put) or tap a screw for grounding, if so how do I do it correctly? The wetness you see is the WD40 I sprayed on the screw heads.



This question may be just from my curiosity. The box looks undamaged and intact. Why change it?  It can be painted to be more aesthetically pleasing and a number of new covers are available to cover the outlet.  What is your goal?

@RMDman If you look at the firs photo (upper left corner), you will see that a screw is broken. That is the screw held ground wire. It was rusted, I was trying to remove the screw to clean the rust. Now, I have no ground. Otherwise, I would do what you suggested. Any suggestions? I would love to solve this problem without removing the box.

Metal conduit like you have there can be used for ground.  The better quality receptacles can use their mounting screws to ground to the box.

@crip659 Any brand model you can give for better quality receptacles? How about using a ground clip.

We do not do recommendations, but if there are 50 cent receptacles and 2.50 dollar receptacles in the same store, the 2.50 will be the ones that are self grounding.

There is nothing special about the location of a ground screw. You could use another screw anchored into the box, or dill a hole and use a bolt and nut to hold the ground wire (just keep it away from other bare wires).'

@ Supertech, Your question asked nothing about needing a new ground screw. Why not ask that question if that is the issue?

@RMDman it became only obvious to me after your comment that if I ground the new GFCI receptacle, I can keep my old box. Do you think, I should modify the question (including the title) or ask a new question in a new thread? I was also thinking maybe I could use grounding clamp or self tapping grounding screws.

You should edit your question.  Just use self tapping ground screws.

Weatherproof?  it looks kind of damp in there.

@Jasen that is Wd40 I sprayed on screw heads.  Box was dry. However I believe it gets wet during winter as cover was broken and gasket was too old. Must be 30 years old.

There do not seem to be any equiment ground wires emerging from the conduit. This is likely because the box is grounded by means of the metal conduit. In that case, you do not need a ground screw or wire in the box, and in any event adding them will do nothing worthwhile. You should use a "self-grounding" GFCI receptacle.

Thank you for catching that. You are right, they have attached grounding pigtail to the box. I was searching for GFCI receptacles.  Google search finds “WR”, weather resistant GFCI receptacles, or self-grounding GFCI receptacles. I cannot find such a thing “weather resistant, self-grounding GFCI receptacle”. Is there such thing ? Or Can I install any self-grounding GFCI receptacle?
